# Compile Cucumber JUnit based runner classes

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, cucumber

I've built a cucumber framework and using JUnit for creating Runner Classes. When I load & run N number of feature files, my runner class is executing all the scenarios & tests as expected.

But here I would like load tests alone in `Eclipse JUnit explorer` by compiling the tests and pick selective tests from there and run from `Eclipse JUnit explorer`.

Currently I could see that after running the tests only `Eclipse JUnit explorer` is populated with tests and from there I'm able to pick and run certain tests. But is there an option to compile and load tests in `Eclipse JUnit explorer`?